# Basic Triangle Geometry on GRE: Length of one side of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Practice GRE problem that is giving me more trouble than it should.  Why is the answer: 'The relationship cannot be determined?'

My answer was that the two quantities are equal--but that is clearly wrong.

[image: GRE Question]

Comment: I'm on shaky ground here, so I could be wrong.  If you assume that $(\overline{HJ})$ and $(\overline{GK})$ are parallel, then you have to have an equilateral triangle, which means that $A$ and $B$ are equal.  Absent such an assumption, as $\angle KGI$ starts close to $(0^\circ)$ and goes to close to $(90^\circ)$, $B$ will go from larger than $A$ to smaller than $A$.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figures on the GRE are not drawn to scale. It is indeed possible that $IJ=5$ (if the triangle is equilateral). It is also possible that $\angle IGK < 60$ and so $IJ<5$. Since there is more than $1$ possibility, the answer is **The relationship cannot be determined**.

Also note that $\angle IGK$ can be more than 60 degrees and $IJ>5.$ In fact by the triangle inequality we have that $0<IK<20$ so $0<IJ<10$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle centered at G with r=10, you can pick up any point K on circle G,  IK and IJ=IK/2 are changing pending on K's choice.